# How to use PHP to send a CSV file to a user through an AJAX call?

Tags: php, ajax, csv

I have a PHP file `dataAPI.php` which returns an array of data that is either serialized as JSON or (as I'm trying to implement) CSV. `dataAPI.php` is accessed exclusively through AJAX calls, which has worked fine so far with JSON data.

The problem is, I want to also have an export button on the client-side, which when clicked, would send another AJAX call to return the same data *serialized in the CSV format*. I know I can't send files over AJAX, so how would I go about doing this?

I've thought of creating CSV files on the server side, and then sending a redirect-url as the response to my AJAX request. If I did this though, how could I prevent two requests overwriting each others files and remove already accessed/old csv files? Is there a better way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question my have the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921037/jquery-table-to-csv-export

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346072/download-csv-file-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning JSON in either case, except that the CSV version would return a JSON object that has one value - a long string containing the CSV data.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in PHP, but the only way to transform an array to the CSV format I see is to output it to a file using `fputcsv()`. Is there a way to turn it into a string directly?

Answer (score 0):

1) For the AJAX call, create the file somewhere on the server and send a link back - this link can then be either redirected to (e.g. in a subwindow), or clicked on...

2) To prevent data being overwritten by different requests, create an unique filename server-side (e.g. with the uniq_id() function). You can still send them with the same filename with a header() tag. Make sure you delete those files once you are sure you no longer need them (I personally use a housekeeping script like the following:

```
$timeout = 43200; // Max age in seconds
$cleanPaths = array("ps_files/"); // The directory to autoclean

foreach ($cleanPaths as $URLPath) {
    if ($handle = opendir($URLPath)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ((substr($file, 0, 1) !== ".") && ((time() - filectime($URLPath . $file)) >= $timeout)) {
                unlink($URLPath . $file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following code in a file and then send an xhr request to it invoking the file. Or you can try opening the file in a separate tool less pop up.

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $csv_output .= $row['Field'].", ";
       $i++;
    }
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
    for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
        $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
```